# Where should I report trademark infringement or illegal SO clones?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites, copyright-infringement, trademark

We all love & benefit from SO, and want to help keeping it profitable. How can we help?

**What counts as trademark infringement:** [Trademark guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)
**What is an illegal SO clone:** [Copyright guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/defending-attribution-required/)

**BTW**: I want to report [stackoverflow.mobi](http://stackoverflow.mobi/). I think it follows the trademark guidelines, but obviously steals the trademark.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are attributing correctly.  And I don't think they are using the name incorrectly.  If you look at the footer they are explicitly stating their purpose.

Comment: Also, since the team has yet to create an official mobile site or app, I think they are fine with clones of this nature.

Comment: @jjnguy, it looks like they follow the attribution guidelines but they do break the trademark guideline about using only *one* of the terms in the product name.

Comment: @Brandon, I see what you mean.

Comment: *Is* the name "Stack Overflow" a registered trademark, though? The logo is. But is the name?

Comment: They just lack of creativity. The obvious name would be **MobileOverflow**.

Comment: @Pekka: dude, check the trademark guidelines link posted above.

Comment: @HuBeZa that's exactly the document I am reading, and  it's not definite on the question. `Our logo images and site names are copyrighted.` Images: not referring to the *name*. Site names: the big question is, what does that mean - StackOverflow *sans* .com, or with? Is "Stack Overflow" in itself a copyrightable trademark, preventing the use of the "Stack Overflow" name on any other TLD? I doubt it. The rest - naming guidelines - is what SO, inc. would *like* other sites to do. That is far from everything in there  actually being enforceable in court.

Comment: @Pekka, I'd tend to agree.  You couldn't trademark 'StackOverflow' since it is a programming term.  Sorry Java, you will have to rename your exception to `OverflowOfTheLIFODataStructureException`.

Comment: @jjnguy yup. I know for a fact that's how it works in Germany - you can't easily trademark vocabulary that is in everyday use. I expect it is at least similar in the US

Comment: @Pekka: you right. It is a tricky one. They could not sue a guy for using the term "stack overflow" in general. Although, Apple [filed a lawsuit for using an apple logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Corps_v_Apple_Computer) - [more than once](http://www.ctv.ca/CTVNews/SciTech/20081004/BC_Apple_Threatens_Suit_081004/), and [for using the letter i](http://www.smh.com.au/digital-life/mp3s/apples-future-wont-be-brought-to-you-by-the-letter-i-20100312-q27r.html). Oh the humanity. I'm glad that IANAL.

Comment: @HuBeZa interesting links!

Comment: Movie companies tell us every time we watch a DVD that the *FBI IS WATCHING YOU WATCH* so I guess we should just call the FBI if someone is stealing stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can contact the team to report this [via the contact link at the bottom of every page](/contact).